# Common law occupation/"co-tenancy" rights trumping lease restrictions on cohabiting or reassigning?

Tags: england-and-wales, common-law, tenancy-rules, assured-shorthold-tenancy

If I'm not mistaken, under [s30, Family Law Act 1996](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/27/section/30) a tenant's spouse or partner implicitly has the same rights to occupy a dwelling let by the tenant themselves and various illegal eviction rulings have affirmed this particularly one involving an African woman in the Midlands that I'll have to look up in order to properly cite.

Meanwhile, many lease agreement contracts contain provisions prohibiting one from granting access or reassigning let premises without the express permission of the landlord. Further, right to rent provisions require landlords to ascertain the identities of all permitted occupiers who may reside in the premisses as their only or principle home. Where is the overlap or intersection of these various doctrines and how do they affect and precedate each other?

---

From Shelter, as linked to below by Steve Melnikoff:

> The right to occupy 'as if' the tenant/licensee

> In many types of tenancy it is necessary for the tenant to be resident in the property in order for the tenancy to retain protection.

> The right of the non-tenant partner to occupy the home as if they were the tenant prevents this provision leading to loss of security where the tenant moves out.[3] If it is a statutory protected tenancy under the Rent Act 1977 or the Rent (Agriculture) Act 1976, which requires the tenant to 'occupy the property as a residence', occupation as a residence by the non-tenant partner will be treated as satisfying this condition. If it is a secure tenancy under the Housing Act 1985 or an assured tenancy under the Housing Act 1988, which requires the tenant to 'occupy the dwelling as her/his only or principal home', occupation as an only or principal home by the non-tenant partner will be treated as satisfying this condition.

> As long as the tenancy continues (ie it has not been ended by the tenant), then even if the tenant leaves, the landlord cannot evict the non-tenant partner unless they would have had the right to claim possession against the tenant. The landlord will have to use the normal procedure to evict the non-tenant partner that they would have had to use to evict the tenant. For example, if the tenant is an assured tenant, the landlord will have to prove one of the grounds for possession, such as rent arrears. In all cases, the landlord must take any possession action against the tenant, not the non-tenant partner.

Comment: Sounds like it may actually be statute law, rather than common law: https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/relationship_breakdown/housing_rights_of_married_sole_tenants/relationship_breakdown_law_for_spouses_and_civil_partners_in_a_sole_tenancy

Comment: ...but it looks like any partner (married or otherwise) can't stay in an AST if they're not also a tenant: https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/relationship_breakdown/housing_rights_of_married_sole_tenants/married_sole_tenants_and_spouses_staying_in_the_home_in_the_long_term#title-2

Comment: As for your second comment, I fail to see the relevance of its attached link, much less how it supports the point suggested by the comment.

Comment: "The remaining spouse has no rights to remain in occupation and the landlord is not legally obliged to get a court order to recover possession. If, however, the landlord uses physical force to evict a tenant, s/he may commit an offence, so in practice the landlord should obtain a court order."

Comment: I can't see where in the kinked-to section it says that, but it seems to me that this may in fact be about scenarios in which two spousal partners are at least somewhat hostile to each other and not cooperating and coordinating or fully agreeing on how to address the housing situation.

Comment: Do people have unprincipled homes? Or did you mean principal?